# How to set fixed footer in Blackberry mobile application

Tags: jquery, html, css, cordova, sticky-footer

I am create blackberry mobile application on Phonegap framework, in that i dont know how to set a fixed footer part please suggest to fix the problem.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

Try using iScroll plugin for this.
http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/